# Правильная разметка HTML

Tags: html, семантика

Как правильнее делать простые элементы, такие как h и p в блоках? Мне сказали что нужно соблюдать семантику и там где подходят эти теги использовать их, но стоит ли к ним привязывать классы, или можно использовать голые теги ?

Comment: если нужен заголовок - используй `h` если нужен абзац текста - `p`. Стилизация к семантике никак не относится. Даже у "голых" тегов есть свои стили, которые могут зависит от браузера, если тебе нужен другой внешний вид - используй классы.